# Devise Confirmable continues to send to localhost:3000 in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, devise-confirmable

I've successfully set up Devise Confirmable with Facebook authentication, and everything works perfectly in development mode. When I push to heroku and run in production mode, the app send an email but the link routes me to:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=E2jH_ehmHwqy2zyvJGcs
```

If I replace localhost:3000 with my app name everything works.

In my config/environments/production.rb file I have the following code:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true 

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :domain => "gmail.com",
  :user_name => ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
  :password => ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"],
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true 
}
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'http://myapp.herokuapp.com' }
```

And in my development I have:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true 
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'http://localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :domain => "gmail.com",
  :user_name => ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
  :password => ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"],
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true 
}
```

Any thoughts on what to do? I couldn't find a straight answer anywhere.

I'm using rails 4 & Devise 3.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The host value is being over written somewhere in your application. Good place to start with is your initializers directory. Like mentioned elsewhere, check setup_mail.rb under initializers.

Goto Rails console and check the output of:

```
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host]
```

Comment: The output is  "http://localhost:3000" but I don't have a setup_mail.rb - and I couldn't find anything linking to this over ride elsewhere. Thoughts on how to change it?

Comment: do a text search on your project files for `default_url_options`

Comment: The only two hits are:                    /config/environments/development.rb:
   31  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
   32  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true 
   33: config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'http://localhost:3000' }
   34  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
   35  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
/config/environments/production.rb:
   94: config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host => 'myapp.herokuapp.com' }
   95  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
   96  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {

2 matches across 2 files

Comment: are you sure the environment is production? Try Rails.env in rails c in server

Comment: When i run the heroku run rails console and the Rails.env command I get "production". Is there another override command i can feed to heroku?

Comment: Any ideas? Can i set this in the rails console?

Comment: Yes, what I had on git was not completely up to date so my git push heroku master wasn't bring over the right host for production.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host => 'your.herokuapp.com' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: "gmail.com",
  Authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: your_username,
  password: your_password
}
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

Comment: Use it without **http://**  simply write `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host => 'your.herokuapp.com' }`

Answer (score 0):

In `production.rb` add `default_url_options` line **before** the smtp settings and also the `host` should not contain `http://`, only write the domain, i.e., `myapp.herokuapp.com`

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'myapp.herokuapp.com' }
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address => "smtp.gmail.com",
:port => 587,
:domain => "gmail.com",
:user_name => ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
:password => ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"],
:authentication => :plain,
:enable_starttls_auto => true 
}
```